# Failed Build with PGS4A. Invalid Build File Error

Tags: java, android, pygame

I am in the process of porting a python game to an Android App. I am using PGS4A for the same.
I have followed all the setup instructions as mentioned here : http://pygame.renpy.org/android-packaging.html

It is only at the last step when i try to build my application into an .apk file for the Android device does it fail.

This is the message that i get once the build fails.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\sony\Desktop\game\pgs4a-0.9.6\pgs4a-0.9.6\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.x
ml:471: Invalid file: C:\Users\sony\Desktop\game\pgs4a-0.9.6\pgs4a-0.9.6\android
-sdk\extras\google\play_licensing\library\build.xml

Total time: 2 seconds

The build seems to have failed.
```

I have gone through forums and other relevant forums for my query (Stack Overflow included) but I couldn't find anything helpful. 
I have gone through https://sites.google.com/site/dustinprinehart/current-projects/float-i-pop/proof-of-concept for ironing out most of the hurdles. But this is a roadblock I cant seem to come out of.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know the cause of you problem but I'm still trying to fix it. PGS4A hasn't been updated to KitKat so the old SDK APIs aren't compatible with the new Licensing library.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out:

It cant find the google play xml file: fix?

- go to the sdk manager
- select extras
- install 11 packages
- accept all
- install

when its done try building again

Comment: I followed your instructions and ended up with the same error.And nowhere does it mention anything about an xml file called fix. Can you expand a bit more?